# How to make the libuvc_ros package

Tags: ros, libuvc-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I downloaded the libuvc_ros from here:
uvc_cam.git
and  I go into the folder:
$ make

I got the following error message:
build/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/ying/Downloads/NASA_object_identification/libuvc_ros" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
make: *** [all] Error 1

Another questions is how to use the camera driver to auto configure the image effect when the light / exposure changes? for example, in sunlight and in shade.  like when in sunlight, the light gain will be decreased and in the shade, the light gain will be increased

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/139251/how-to-make-the-libuvc_ros-package/) by [JennyLu](https://answers.ros.org/users/13221/jennylu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-03-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [evk02](https://answers.ros.org/users/11636/evk02/) on 2014-03-12**:
You should download it from git https://github.com/ktossell/libuvc_ros.git into your src folder and then from the catkin folder run catkin_make_isolated --pkg libuvc_camer --install

**Comment by [jbinney](https://answers.ros.org/users/3292/jbinney/) on 2014-03-12**:
What ROS distro are you on? I think the last time i tried that package was on fuerte; i don't see branches in the repo for groovy or hydro

**Comment by [JennyLu](https://answers.ros.org/users/13221/jennylu/) on 2014-03-12**:
@evk02 Thanks for the reply, that's what I used to download the source code from git. I am using groovy distro right now

**Comment by [JennyLu](https://answers.ros.org/users/13221/jennylu/) on 2014-03-12**:
@jbinney I am using Groovy. I learned from here: http://wiki.ros.org/libuvc_camera And download the source from https://github.com/ktossell/libuvc_ros.git , which is said to be in master branch

**Comment by [JennyLu](https://answers.ros.org/users/13221/jennylu/) on 2014-03-12**:
@evk02  Thanks for the update, I have no problem with uvc_camera at all, but I want to get access to the file where I can adjust the exposure parameters. Because right now when working outside with other software to take videos, my Logitech HD Pro Webcam C910 works perfect, but in ROS too bright

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry, not in front on my computer, but I believe uvc_camera uses camera1394, where you can set brightness, see details at (look for brightness under parameters section):
http://wiki.ros.org/camera1394

If you are not sure how to use parameters, the best to use a launch file. Example http://answers.ros.org/question/9786/how-do-you-configure-uvc_camera/

---

Originally posted by [evk02](https://answers.ros.org/users/11636/evk02/) with karma: 218 on 2014-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JennyLu](https://answers.ros.org/users/13221/jennylu/) on 2014-03-17**:
It seems my camera is not a IEEE 1394 camera. So when I  followed the tutorial here: http://wiki.ros.org/camera1394/Tutorials/ConnectingToIEEE1394Camera, to run the camera driver. I get error. For the launch file to set parameters, it seems the parameters are width heigth fps, etc